# creating a podspec for a third party static library

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to build a cocoa pod that includes a third party static library and some of my source code.  I am unable to get the linker to find the library.  My directory structure is:

```
classes
-- (my .m and .h files)
libs
  foo.z    #-- third party static library
```

when I build, I get the linker error:

```
ld: library not found for -llibs/foo.a
```

My podspec is as follows

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "FOO"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "summary"

  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   description
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "xxx"
  s.license      = 'MIT'
  s.author       = { "me" => "me@xyz.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, '6.1'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '6.1'
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/<some repository>" }
  s.source_files  = 'Classes', 'Classes/**/*.{h,m}'

  s.preserve_paths   = 'libs/foo.a'
  s.vendored_library = 'libs/foo.a'

  s.library     = 'foo'

  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.requires_arc = true

end
```

Comment: Any luck? I have a similar problem with my static library but in my case I get errors for duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The line `s.library = 'foo'` might be your problem.

The `library` attribute indicates **libraries to be linked against**, such as `xml2`, `zlib`, etc, and it looks like you're telling it to look for a third-party library that has the name as your library.

See the documentation for it [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#libraries).